# htaccess for CORS in javascript

Tags: php, .htaccess, cors

*(Note: In the Network activity tab, just before login.php, on localhost:8080 I expected to see some notification that `.htaccess` had been accessed, but it is not there. However, I now know it is being accessed, because I have looked in Apaches error log file and found this:*

```
[Sat Oct 14 21:57:01.943348 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3944:tid 1172] [client ::1:57586] C:/wamp64/www/mysite/phpgeneral/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost:52656/mysite/index.html
[Sat Oct 14 21:58:39.918523 2017] [core:alert] [pid 3944:tid 1164] [client ::1:57599] C:/wamp64/www/mysite/phpgeneral/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost:52656/mysite/index.html
```

*My `.htaccess file is exactly written as found below. Should those command have something wrapped around it?*

**Original Question.**

I am making a cross origin script request:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/mysite/login.php";
var method = "POST";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
}

if (!xhr) {
    return;
}
// Response handlers.
xhr.onload = function (data) {
    if (data.srcElement) {
        var json = eval('(' + data.srcElement.response + ')');
        MyCallback(json);
    }
};
xhr.onerror = function (data) {
    alert("Error (Process Failure): " + textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
};
xhr.send();
```

In the directory where login.php is located I have the following in `.htaccess`:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I get the errors:

```
SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:52656 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80700013, Could not complete the operation due to error 80700013.
```

**Could anyone tell me how to get this cross origin script working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user4035 answered this in another thread

> Try loading headers_module inside Apache config

Answer (score 0):

Change the `set` in the `.htaccess` to `add`

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header add Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but still the same two errors. (I shut down Wamp first and restarted as is required.)

Answer (score 0):

Giving the full domain works for me

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "yourdomain.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the directory where the php script resides does not know all the domains from where the script will be called.